# Azure DNS - On Prem to Azure via VPN - Keeping things internal?

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, internal-dns, azure-networking

We have a VPN that connects our onsite network to an Azure VNET. We want to delegate a DNS subdomain from our onsite DNS to our Azure DNS. If we use the Azure public DNS then we are given four Azure DNS servers with public ip addresses but what we really want are private ip addresses on the DNS servers so we can keep all DNS traffic internal (via VPN). Obviously we could deploy our own DNS solution on a VM in Azure but we are trying to use the Azure provided facilities where possible.

My questions then are:

1. Is there a way to make use of the Azure DNS without making request via the public internet?
2. If not what is a lightweight DNS solution we could use to deploy/configure on a VM? - dnsmasq??

Thanks for any help

Phill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it appears not. It looks like the only way to keep the DNS requests internal is to deploy and manage your own dns instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Azure Private DNS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-overview)?

Comment: Hi Sam, we've got private dns set up for the auto-registration functionality but I don't think it is possible to delegate a zone/domain to it from an on prem DNS server? I might be missing something so if it is possible I'd love to know how. Our on prem DNS is run by a different team who are not really geared up to deal with the number of changes we might want to make in DNS as part of our RnD efforts so we thought the best option was for them to delegate a domain which would then be under our control and would allow us to automate the lifecycle of records in the name server.